# How to mock setFirstResult() setMaxResult() in junit

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have written a method that applies pagination using hibernate. I am writing junit test method to verify the functionality but I am unable to mock setFirstResult() and setMaxResult() due to this reason it always returns a list with all the objects. Please find below the code for your reference

```
public List<Issuance> getIssuances(int after, int limit) {
        CriteriaBuilder builder = db.session().getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Issuance> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(Issuance.class);
        Root<Issuance> txnRoot = criteriaQuery.from(Issuance.class);
        Path<Long> idPath = txnRoot.get("id");
        criteriaQuery.select(txnRoot);
        criteriaQuery.orderBy(builder.desc(idPath));
        return db.session().createQuery(criteriaQuery).setFirstResult(after).setMaxResults(limit).getResultList();
    }
```

**junit method**

```
  @Test
    public void getIssuances(){
        Issuance issuance1 = new Issuance();
        issuance1.setId(1l);

        Issuance issuance2 = new Issuance();
        issuance1.setId(2l);

        Issuance issuance3 = new Issuance();
        issuance1.setId(3l);
        List<Issuance> expectedIssuances = Arrays.asList(issuance1,issuance2,issuance3);

        CriteriaQuery<Issuance> criteriaQuery = mock(CriteriaQuery.class);
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = mock(CriteriaBuilder.class);
        when(dbSession.getCriteriaBuilder()).thenReturn(criteriaBuilder);
        Root<Issuance> txnRoot = mock(Root.class);

        when(criteriaBuilder.createQuery(eq(Issuance.class))).thenReturn(criteriaQuery);
        when(criteriaQuery.from(eq(Issuance.class))).thenReturn(txnRoot);

        Query<Issuance> query = mock(Query.class);

        when(query.setFirstResult(eq(0))).thenReturn(query);
        when(query.setMaxResults(eq(1))).thenReturn(query);
        when(query.getResultList()).thenReturn(expectedIssuances);
        when(dbSession.createQuery(eq(criteriaQuery))).thenReturn(query);

        List<Issuance> result = unit.getIssuances(0,1);
        assertNotEquals(expectedIssuances.size(), result.size());// test case fails because the both objects are equal
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw this error today and managed to solve it, I know it's been a while, but I'll answer if anyone needs help.

```
//use de ArgumentCaptor to capture an argument passed to a method
ArgumentCaptor<Integer> setFirstResultCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Integer.class);

ArgumentCaptor<Integer> setMaxResultsCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Integer.class);

Mockito.when(queryMock.setFirstResult(setFirstResultCaptor.capture())).thenReturn(queryMock);

Mockito.when(queryMock.setMaxResults(setMaxResultsCaptor.capture())).thenReturn(queryMock);
```